# Cocoa style guidelines for an init method with BOOL variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a data class that starts with a bool value:

```
- (id)initWithBool:(BOOL)hasSomeValue anotherVariable:(var type)var ...
```

But this is unreadable when instantiating in XCode, because "hasSomeValue" is not shown when auto-complete appears.

```
-(id)initWithHasSomeValue:(BOOL)hasSomeValue anotherVariable:(var type)var ...
```

Is also rather clunky.  I've done some searching but can't seem to find Apple's recommended specs on this.

EDIT: A pointer to an example by Apple would help very much. I still haven't managed to find one.

Comment: What does the boolean value represent?

Comment: Whether it has an object of a certain type.  For example, if it has WidgetX, then the remaining data in the object relates to that object or how to handle data without it.

Answer (score 2):

You'd really want something that tells you WHAT the BOOL actually represents

```
- (id)initWithBool:(BOOL)hasSomeValue ...
- (id)initWithHasSomeValue:(BOOL)hasSomeValue ...
```

would be comparable to

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)string ...
```

if you were initiating a BOOL (which clearly is nonsense), except with `[NSNumber numberWithBool:]`

Comment: I understand the semantic comparisons, I simply didn't know if there was a guideline for an init method that has BOOL as it's first parameter (it's not the only one).

Comment: The cocoa guidelines for naming methods: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF, doesn't seem to be anything specific for your question.

Comment: Yes I reviewed these previously but couldn't find anything on it.  Perhaps from a design standpoint it's bad practice to have a bool as the first variable in an init method?  If so, I'd like to find out why.  Strange that I can't find any examples of initing with bool.

Comment: I can't think of any reason of why it would be bad in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the name of the parameter should describe its semantics, which "bool" doesn't really do. E.g. "initWithName:" is better than "initWithString:".

Even more generally speaking, you have a data class that takes a boolean as it's first parameter? Maybe you need to rethink why it's there at all?

Comment: "rethink why it's there at all" - Could you give an example as to why?

Comment: What he means, I think, is that you should not write code that's not directly useful (it's more maintenance, more risk). If you feel your code is clunky due to those methods, it might signal an architecture issue, hence you should rethink it to see if it really is what you want.

Comment: Yes, this makes more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the custom init method to your header file?

Although it will compile (with a warning) and run fine, the custom init method will only appear in auto complete if it appears in the header file.

Comment: Auto-complete works, but it doesn't show "hasSomeValue," it only shows initWithBool:(BOOL)

Comment: Oh right, I see same behaviour sometimes; why does it matter for you, just a case of tidyness?

Comment: I feel like it's hard to read.  It should be more descriptive.  For some reason it doesn't feel like it fits Apple's coding style, but perhaps it's just me.  I ended up changing it to the second one.